# Parsing XML with different elements

Tags: xml, parsing, go

I am not able to understand, how to create structure, because every monitor elements are different from one another, please help me

```
<cm>
    <id>MONIT_SYNC</id>
    <monitor name="APPLICATION_MONITOR">
        <name>AD</name>
        <script>AD.exe</script>
        <freq>1</freq>   
    </monitor>

 <monitor name="EVENTLOGS">
        <alert>1</alert>
        <freq>15</freq>
        <eventlog>Active Directory Web Service</eventlog>
        <event_include>Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Server</event_include>
        <event_exclude/>
        <sops/>
    </monitor>
<monitor name="PING">
        <reqid>2579643</reqid>
        <alert>1</alert>
        <freq>2</freq>
        <repeatfreq>1</repeatfreq>
        <repeatcount>1</repeatcount>
        <wmi-cred>
            <![CDATA[test\test;test]]>
        </wmi-cred>
        <snmp-str>null</snmp-str>
        <hosts>172.24.221.140</hosts>
        <hung_monitor>0</hung_monitor>
        <ipswmi>172.24.221.140</ipswmi>
        <sops/>
    </monitor>
</cm>
```

I am not able get every monitor has different  elements in it.

Comment: All capitals is considered shouting, I don't recommend it.

Answer (score -1):

HERE YOU CAN FIND THE LIVE TRY,I TRIED AND I SUCCEED https://play.golang.org/p/vxfBIlZuPd

I HOPE I DID WHAT YOU WANT